# Installing Mysql with Nodejs

Tags: mysql

I am new to nodejs. I have installed the nodejs on my window 8 system. The path is 
C:\Program Files\nodejs. I want to install Mysql module for nodejs, But when i type command in search. Two command prompt displayed :-

1 Command Prompt
2 nodejs Command Prompt.

When i open 1 and type npm install mysql it give me error. But when i click on 2 a shell gets opened. After that i type command npm install mysql . It installed the mysql module but on different location C:\Users\user\node_modules. That's why i am confused how mysql will work bcoz both path are different. Please help me in installing mysql with nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

A little inspection would tell you the difference - right click on either link, properties and see what it says. The former is the plain vanilla command prompt. Looking at the latter, it runs a file called nodevars.bat which ensures your node.js and npm are first in path (and other things. READ IT!). That makes sure that node.js commands like npm would work without a full path. When *running* node.js projects *always* use the latter link

The properties of my node.js Command prompt looks like this

[image: enter link description here]

Inspect the nodevars.bat file and you will find

> rem If we're in the node.js directory, change to the user's home dir.
>   if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"

Which is how a module in /users/ will work. You're already there.

However, what you installed is the node.js *module* for using mysql. You will still need to install a proper copy of mysql- [the installer is here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/), and node.js, set up properly will use it. I believe the module should do it automatically

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js) is worth a read - you're trying to do what fmsf is talking about essentially.

I'd note I've never coded mysql and node.js together before. However most of these things are publicly available and a few quick google searches should help you massively, as would a little curiosity. Don't just code. Grok!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that should be noted here: you can install packages locally *or* globally, for example if you would want to use mysql as an app system-wide you could use `npm install -g mysql`. Not all modules work that way, still it is important to note that.

Seems to me you are trying to install `mysql` locally, but you are (from what I saw in your post) in a wrong directory.

In other words - if you want to make a local installation, then you can do as you did before, but from inside the project directory

This is an example how I would install `mysql` as a dependency to a new project I have not been working in yet (without much detail such as using `git` and stuff like that):

1. Open up terminal, check what directory I am in and what's up via `ls` (`dir` in case of Windows terminal);
2. Create a directory for my project `mkdir ./Whatever` (again on Windows it probably would be `mkdir .\whatever`);
3. I would then `cd ./whatever` (WINDOWS: `chdir .\whatever`) to my directory;

Then I would be able to install stuff to this project.

At that point I might do something like `npm install mysql --save` which would not only install mysql module to ./node_modules (inside a directory I am in), but also make a note of it in my `package.json`

By the way, I think you could try `npm init` in educational purposes, to get a hold on some stuff like `package.json`, which is quite important in nodejs.

Don't be afraid to spoil something, if you are working in a scope of a directory you can just get rid of it easily.

Long story short: don't use `npm install stuff` just anywhere, it is not python's `pip install` - go to intended directory instead. And check directories you've already been to, perhaps those are full of unintended `node_modules` (or other) directories.

Also, it might be useful to check your %PATH% variable and system-wide env. variables, cuz those tend to get clogged sometimes.

**PS**

I might be off with some of the provided Windows commands, check if those are correct before trying to use them.